# How to calculate the SHAP values for the probability of a LightGBM binary classification model

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, lightgbm, shap

I modeled a LGBM binary classification model, however I am not interested in the classification itself, I am interested in the probabilities of a given set of observations to output a positive classification.

I wanted to see how my model works using SHAP values, but I am struggling to find how to find the SHAP values for the probability values, mainly because the output is a vector with two values.

Here is how I tried to do it:

```
import shap

model = LGBMClassifier()
model = model.fit(X_train,y_train)

# Get SHAP values
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model,
    data=X_train,
    feature_perturbation="interventional",
    model_output="probability")
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_train)
```

The only plot that works with the SHAP values generated is the summary plot, which vale values that range from -0.2 to 0.4 .

I just want to be safe that those values are really referring to probabilities and would like to see it in a force plot, waterfall plot or any other plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `link="logit"` for the `force_plot`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import shap
import lightgbm as lgbm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from scipy.special import expit

shap.initjs()

data = load_breast_cancer()

X = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=data.feature_names)
y = data.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42
)

model = lgbm.LGBMClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

explainer_raw = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer_raw(X_train)

# force plot of first row for class 1
class_idx = 1
row_idx = 0
expected_value = explainer_raw.expected_value[class_idx]
shap_value = shap_values[:, :, class_idx].values[row_idx]

shap.force_plot(
    base_value=expected_value,
    shap_values=shap_value,
    features=X_train.iloc[row_idx, :],
    link="logit",  # <-- here
)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know why the result is plotted as 1.00 when the f(x) tick is between 0.988 and 0.998?
I will just be able to test your solution Monday, I will tell you if it worked.

Comment: @EduardoPitta It already works because it's fully [reprex]. Though I will be grateful if you accept it.

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain to me why of the tick position?
And I'm working in Databricks and I can't seem to get shap.initjs() working.
matplotlib = True is not yet supported for force plots with multiple samples.

Comment: Upper X axis are raw scores passed through sigmoid (i.e. probabilities). Lower display are feature values and their impact on probability

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov: This is simply a formatting thing. The text label does not use the same formatting as the plotting backend. It does not matter.

Comment: @MichaelM Is it a statement or a question? If it's the latter, you may think for while why SHAP is additive in raw scores space and if additivity still preserved after passing through sigmoid.

Comment: My bad. I used the wrong "at". I intended to explain the question of @EduardoPitta in the comments.

Comment: @MichaelM Fully agreed